# FreeNAS VM's not starting

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, freebsd, nas

I am running FreeNAS 11.1-U5 at home. I have everything configured and have created VM's for Windows Server, Ubuntu, pfSense, FreePBX. I was able to install Windows and Ubuntu, but shortly after (a few hours after installing them), and after turning them off through the FreeNAS GUI, they have stopped turning on. FreeNAS reports at the top of the GUI that the start was successful, but the VM details still read "stopped".

I have run the VM's before and have the required settings in my CMOS configured for the Host (FreeNAS machine). Restarting the host will fix the problem for a while and it will let me work with the VM's, but I cannot keep restarting FreeNAS. Can anyone tell me why this happens and how to fix it please?